# Break up Text string to use in Join in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good Day,

I am busy creating a tax document for discount entries out of our debtors transaction table. One of the requirements is that the discount amount must indicate to which transaction it relates. This information is available but I do not know how to use it because it is in a single delimited text field. The table looks as follows.

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦══════╦════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ AutoIdx ║ TxDate     ║ Id   ║ Amount ║ Reference ║ cAllocs                                  ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1       ║ 30-07-2014 ║ OInv ║ 100    ║ IN543     ║ I=4;A=99;D=20140730|I=3;A=1;D=20140730   ║
║ 2       ║ 30-07-2014 ║ OInv ║ 200    ║ IN544     ║ I=4;A=198;D=20140730|I=3;A=2;D=20140730  ║
║ 3       ║ 30-07-2014 ║ DS   ║ 3      ║ DISC      ║ I=1;A=1;D=20140730|I=2;A=2;D=20140730    ║
║ 4       ║ 30-07-2014 ║ Pmnt ║ 297    ║ PMNT      ║ I=1;A=99;D=20140730|I=2;A=198;D=20140730 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩══════╩════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

In the column cAllocs you have the information that links the lines with each other. It has three indicators
I - the line in this table that it links to
A - the amount of the link transaction
D - the date of the transaction
It can have only one set of these or many sets delimited with a pipe character.

I want to end up with a table that has only the entries with Id "DS" but giving me the reference column value of the lines it links to in a single column (they can be delimited by comma)

So from the above table I would like to get this result.

```
╔════════════╦════╦════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╗
║ TxDate     ║ Id ║ Amount ║ Reference ║ MatchedTo   ║
╠════════════╬════╬════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 30-07-2014 ║ DS ║ 3      ║ DISC      ║ IN543,IN544 ║
╚════════════╩════╩════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

Thanks for any replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that handles string manipulation and retrieves the data at the same time. Try this one below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetReferenceFromCAllocs](@cAllocs VARCHAR(MAX))RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)AS
    BEGIN   
        DECLARE @val AS VARCHAR(MAX) 
        DECLARE @ch AS CHAR(1)
        DECLARE @result AS VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @returnValue AS VARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @val = @cAllocs
        SET @result = ''
        SET @returnValue = ''

        DECLARE @idx INT
        SET @idx = 1
        WHILE @idx < LEN(@val)
            BEGIN
                SET @ch = SUBSTRING(@val,@idx,1)
                IF(@ch = 'I')
                    BEGIN
                        DECLARE @idx2 INT
                        DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(5)

                        SET @temp = @ch
                        SET @idx2 = @idx + 1

                        SET @ch = SUBSTRING(@val,@idx2,1)

                        WHILE @ch <> ';'
                            BEGIN
                                SET @temp = @temp + @ch

                                SET @idx2 = @idx2 + 1
                                SET @ch = SUBSTRING(@val,@idx2,1)
                            END
                        SET @idx = @idx2
                        SET @result = @result + @temp + ';'
                    END
                ELSE
                    SET @idx = @idx + 1
            END 

        SET @idx = 1
        WHILE @idx < LEN(@result)
            BEGIN
                SET @ch = SUBSTRING(@val,@idx,1)
                    IF(@ch = '=')
                        BEGIN
                            SET @temp = ''
                            SET @idx2 = @idx + 1

                            SET @ch = SUBSTRING(@result,@idx2,1)

                            WHILE @ch <> ';'
                                BEGIN
                                    SET @temp = @temp + @ch

                                    SET @idx2 = @idx2 + 1
                                    SET @ch = SUBSTRING(@result,@idx2,1)    
                                END
                            SET @idx = @idx2

                            DECLARE @tempValue AS VARCHAR(10)
                            SET @tempValue = ''

                            SELECT @tempValue = Reference FROM YOUR_TABLE
                            WHERE AutoIdx = @temp

                            SET @returnValue = @returnValue + @tempValue + ','
                        END
                    ELSE
                        SET @idx = @idx + 1
            END 

        RETURN SUBSTRING(@returnValue,1, LEN(@returnValue)-1)
    END
```

--EDIT: The function above will get all data with I as it's prefix:
E.g:

```
Passed Value: I=4;A=99;D=20140730|I=3;A=1;D=20140730 
Result Value: I=4;I=3;
```

After that, it queries the corresponding Reference with AutoIdx 4 and 3; then returns it in a format as specified in your question.

Then, run this sql:

```
SELECT 
    yt.TxDate, 
    yt.Id, 
    yt.Amount, 
    yt.Reference,
    dbo.GetReferenceFromCAllocs(yt.cAllocs) AS MatchedTo
FROM YOUR_TABLE yt
WHERE yt.Id = 'DS'
```

Hope this would work. Just adjust the SQL codes to optimize it. I'm in a hurry so I used safest values (such as VARCHAR(MAX)).

Comment: In my suggestion, JOIN is not needed. But if you need use JOIN, then my suggestion is not applicable.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked great. I do need to join to other tables as well but could use this to create a temp table and then join from there.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can continue on this thread or start a new one, but I have ran into some problems using the above function. Sometimes I get a error when using the function in the SELECT query as suggested above:
 Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 3
Error converting data type varchar to bigint